# Does Python automatically use swap memory?

Tags: python, memory

I wrote a Python wrapper for a big data R library. It's primary use is to:

1. receive a potentially large amount of data as an `R dataframe/tibble`
2. convert that to a `Pandas dataframe`
3. convert that to a `Koalas dataframe`

So I am worried about running out of memory. I'm not really worried about how fast it is because it's kind of a workaround, but it just has to be reliable. Also not looking to handle this is a formalized pipeline.

Will Python automatically `swap` my data onto disk if my users run out of RAM for some reason? Does the fact that it is running in a Docker env have any impact on that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Python doesn't know anything about physical memory, instead it's abstracted away by the OS as [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: Just an anecdotal experience: I don't think python will handle large amounts of data too well since I have blue-screened my computer by trying to load ~84 GB of data in python.

Comment: This is entirely up to the OS memory manager. Most modern OSs do swap RAM to disk automatically.  Swap is no kind of panacea however. Data on disk is ~10^6 times slower to access than RAM. The number of situations where this difference doesn't matter is much smaller than you'd like. If data is bigger than RAM, only a trivial sequential transformation will finish in this century. I don't know if the conversions you mention are in that category.